# Django 2.0 : raises unbound error

Tags: django, forms

i was working with Django 1.11 and created a template that contains a formset. everything worked fine. 
but i've upgraded Django to Django 2.0 now and my template raises :

> sequence item 5: expected str instance, BoundField found

i'm stucking here without knowing why would such an error accure when it was working with Django 1.11

here is my template where my form:

```
<table style ="border-collapse: separate;border-spacing: 15px;" id="id_forms_table">

        <tr><td width="5%">N P</td><td width="8%">Date d'operation</td><td width="25%">Désignation</td><td width="10%">Type tiers</td><td width="10%">Tiers</td><td width="10%">Référence de Facture</td><td width="10%">Montant Débit</td><td width="10%">Montant Crédit</td></tr>
        {% for form in formset %}
     <tr style="border:1px solid black;" id="{{ form.prefix }}-row" class="dynamic-form" >

        <td{% if forloop.first %} class="" {% endif %}><div class="col-xs-1"><b><p name="np1">1</p></b></div></td>

        <td>
            {% render_field form.dateOperation1 class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputName" name="designation1" %}{{form.dateOperation1.errors}}

        </td>
        <td>{% render_field form.designation1  class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputName" placeholder="Designation opération" name="datefacture1" %}{{form.designation1.errors}}

        </td>
        <td>
            {% render_field form.typeTiers1 class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputName" placeholder="Montant HT" %}{{form.typeTiers1.errors}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {% render_field form.tiers1 class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputName" placeholder="TVA" name="tiers" %}{{form.tiers1.errors}}
        </td>
        <td>{% render_field form.numfacture1 class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputName" placeholder="" name="mttc1" %}{{form.numfacture1.errors}}
        </td>
        <td>{% render_field form.montantdebit1 class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputName" placeholder="Montant" name="mttc1" %}{{form.montantdebit1.errors}}
        </td>
        <td>{% render_field form.montantcredit1 class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputName" placeholder="Montant" name="mttc1" %}{{form.montantcredit1.errors}}
        </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}<tr>
        </tr></table>
```

forms.py :

```
class FormBanque(forms.Form):
 dateOperation1=forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)
 designation1=forms.CharField()
 typeTiers1=MyModelChoiceField1(queryset=operation_Bancaire.objects.all(),to_field_name='type_tiers',required=False)
 tiers1=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=operation_Bancaire.objects.none())
 numfacture1=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=client.objects.all().values_list('nom', flat=True),required=False)
 montantdebit1=forms.CharField()
 montantcredit1=forms.CharField()
BanqueFormSet=formset_factory(FormBanque)
```

Here is my view:

```
class BanqueViews(TemplateView):

def get(self, request,*args,**kwargs):
    if request.user.is_active :
        current_user = request.user
        form1=banque()
        form2=AjoutFrs()
        formset = BanqueFormSet()
        context={"formset":formset,"current_user":current_user,"form2":form2,"form1":form1}
        return render(request,"appOne/banquemineFormsPy.html", context)
```

here is the full Traceback :

```
Environment:
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/banque

Django Version: 2.0.1
Python Version: 3.6.2
Installed Applications:
['appOne',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'widget_tweaks']
  Installed Middleware:
 ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
 Template error:
  In template C:\version21\DjangoProj\tsite\appOne\templates\appOne\banquemineFormsPy.html, error at line 71
   sequence item 5: expected str instance, BoundField found
  61 :  
  62 : 
  63 : 
  64 : 
  65 : <br> 
  66 : 
  67 : <!-- Formulaire d'ajout des liiigneee <td width="10%" 
  colspan="2">Importer la piece Justificatif</td> -->
  68 : <table style ="border-collapse: separate;border-spacing: 15px;" 
   id="id_forms_table">
    69 :            
    70 :            <tr><td width="5%">N P</td><td width="8%">Date 
   d'operation</td><td width="25%">Désignation</td><td width="10%">Type tiers</td><td width="10%">Tiers</td><td width="10%">Référence de Facture</td><td width="10%">Montant Débit</td><td width="10%">Montant Crédit</td></tr>
   71 :              {% for form in formset %} 
   72 :          <tr style="border:1px solid black;" id="{{ form.prefix }}- 
   row" class="dynamic-form" >
   73 : 
    74 :            <td{% if forloop.first %} class="" {% endif %}><div 
  class="col-xs-1"><b><p name="np1">1</p></b></div></td>
    75 : 
    76 :            <td>
     77 :               {% render_field form.dateOperation1 class="form- 
       control" id="inlineFormInputName" name="designation1" %} 
             {{form.dateOperation1.errors}}
         78 :               
        79 :            </td>
       80 :             <td>{% render_field form.designation1  class="form- 
   control" id="inlineFormInputName" placeholder="Designation opération" 
  name="datefacture1" %}{{form.designation1.errors}}
     81 : 


  Traceback:

   File "C:\Users\users MGE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
    32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
      35.             response = get_response(request)
     File "C:\Users\users MGE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
      32\lib\site- 
        packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
            128.                 response = 
         self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

      File "C:\Users\users MGE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
       32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
      126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, 
         *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

           File "C:\Users\users MGE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
      32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
       69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

      File "C:\Users\users MGE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
      32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
         89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

      File "C:\version21\DjangoProj\tsite\appOne\views.py" in get
     178.           return render(request,"appOne/banquemineFormsPy.html", context)
      File "C:\Users\users MGE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
          32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
         36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, 
        request, using=using)

             File "C:\Users\users MGE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
          32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
             62.     return template.render(context, request)

            File "C:\Users\users MGE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
          32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
            61.             return self.template.render(context)

           File "C:\Users\users MGE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
         32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
           175.                     return self._render(context)

           File "C:\Users\users MGE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
        32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
             167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

        File "C:\Users\users MGE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
       32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
       943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

       File "C:\Users\users MGE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
       32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
       910.             return self.render(context)

       File "C:\Users\users MGE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
      32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
        58.                 result = self.nodelist.render(context)

       File "C:\Users\users MGE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
       32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
       943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

       File "C:\Users\users MGE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
       32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
       910.             return self.render(context)

       File "C:\Users\users MGE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
       32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
       218.         return mark_safe(''.join(nodelist))

      Exception Type: TypeError at /banque
       Exception Value: sequence item 5: expected str instance, BoundField 
       found
```

Can you help me notice what's the problem. i'm stucking in a problem that i didn't expect

Thank You

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Thank you for your replay , i've added my traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've resolved the issue by going back to Django 1.11 instead of 2.0

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading django 1.11 to django 2.1, I had a similar issue. The below tweak helped.

Changed the last line of widget_tweaks.py

`return bounded_field`
  to
`return str(bounded_field)`.

Answer (score 1):

I hade this problem once in pythonanywhere.

You can just update the django-widget-tweaks

```
pip upgrade django-widget-tweaks
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have hit [this issue](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks/issues/54) in django-widget-tweaks. It's been fixed in [pull request 57](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks/pull/57) but it doesn't look like there has been a release yet.

If you want to continue using Django 2.0, you could try installing the master branch, or you could try the fork `django-widgets-improved` mentioned on the pull request.

Another option would be to downgrade to 1.11 LTS for now.

Comment: but i have other templates where i worked with widget-tweaks. and they work fine. the difference between those templates and this one is that on this this template(where the error accured) i'm working with formset not a normal form

Comment: I don't use django-widget-tweaks so I can't help any further. I think it's worth trying the fixes I suggested. Your error message exactly matches the one in the bug report.

Comment: okey thank you so much for your time. i will see fixes you suggested